# Perform a maven plugin execution only when a file changed since last build

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I want to execute a maven plugin during `mvn clean install` whenever a file is changed since the last build. If the file is not changed since the last build then plugin execution should be skipped during `mvn clean install`.

Is it possible to achieve this in maven 3.5.0?

Comment: The `clean` goal removes all generated files, so all will be regenerated. You can just do `mvn install` to reuse previously generated artifacts that are still up to date.

Comment: @MartinHöller Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven doesn't keep record of all modules it ever built. However, this would be necessary if Maven would have to know if some (source) files changed.

Some plugins, like the `maven-compiler-plugin`, compare timestamps of source-files with timestamps of corresponding, generated class-files, which allows to skip compilation if classfile is newer. However, if you execute `mvn clean` (as mentioned in the question), class files are removed and compilation thus has to be executed anyway.

So to conculde: your request cannot be fulfilled by maven without major changes in maven itself.